# How to make a httpclient get request with header, payload and body? Angular API

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to call an API, with get method, with header, payload and body.
Please, help me, if its possible, one example.

Comment: What you have tried ? Follow the angular documentation https://angular.io/guide/http for the step by step implementation

Comment: I was following the doc, but I am a beginner, and there, I didnt find where and how to do the payload part

Comment: You the this video for angular learning https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5E2AVpwsko

Comment: Are you really sure, you need a GET request with a payload body? Although not explicitely forbidden this is very uncommon ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try in that way

```
const userData: any = {
  example1: example1,
  example2: example2,
  example3: example3,
};
this.apiCall(userData);

 }  

apiCall(userData) {
  this.http.get<any>('api_link', userData).subscribe(data => {
    console.log('response: ', data);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the payload being sent to the API? Then that is a POST call and the payload goes in the body. For example:

```
 const payloadUrl = "some_url"; 

 const body = {
          payload: "payload";
 }            

 postPayload(): Observable<any> {
          return this.http.post<any>(this.payloadUrl, body, httpOptions)
            .pipe(
              catchError(this.handleError('error', error))
            );
  }
```

Comment: How can i put coduser: integer in payload, please?
And where i can put the body (fields)

Comment: `const body = { coduser: integer; }`

Comment: the `body` goes in this.http.post<any>(this.payloadUrl, **body**)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use $q to resolve promise and $http to send get request with headers**.

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
var req = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: "some url",
    headers:{}
};

$http(req).success(function (res, status, headers, config) {
    deferred.resolve(res);
}).error(function (res) {
    deferred.reject(res);
});
```